# Chrome crashed when using visual studio code debug console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

### [Description]

I'm building an IDE for developing a chrome extension by using **visual studio code** + **debugger for chrome extension**. After some trial & error, I ran source java-script successfully by using **Attach to chrome, with sourcemaps** debug mode. But chrome always crash immediately when I use the debug console ...
How can I fix that?

### [Symptoms]

Debugger paused on breakpoint, but chrome always crash immediately when I use the debug console.
[image: chrome_crash]

chrome crash log
[image]

### [Environment]

- Ubuntu 17.10
- Visual Studio Code 1.18.1
- Debugger for Chrome 3.5.0
- Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84
- launch.json

  ```
  {
      // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
      // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
      // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
          {
              "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
              "type": "chrome",
              "request": "launch",
              "url": "http://10.19.202.100:8080",
              "sourceMaps": true,
              "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
          },
          {
              "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
              "type": "chrome",
              "request": "attach",
              "port": 9222,
              "sourceMaps": true,
              "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src"
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Root cause]

- Exception: Natives disabled
- **Chrome stable version can't enable native client**
  [image]

### [Solution]

- Uninstall Chrome (stable channel)
- Install [Chrome (dev channel)](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html?platform=linux&extra=devchannel)
- Start Chrome from console

  ```
  google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --enable-nacl
  ```
- Run VSCode debug with **Attach to chrome, with sourcemap**
- Enjoy it!!
  [image]

### [Reference]

- [How to enable Native Client in Google Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/native_client/src/native_client/+/master/docs/native_client_in_google_chrome.md)